# Vertical lines going beyond the borders of my table

Tags: tables

I am very new to LaTeX so please excuse the amateur question. I am creating a table using the following commands:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\small
\centering
\caption{Effect of industry on \emph{Bad Self Impact} by value of \emph{Cultural Sentiment}}.
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\\ 
\hline
Value of \emph{Cultural Sentiment}  & Coefficient on \emph{Import Industry}  & P-value & Observations\\ \hline
Positive & 0.234 (-0.108, 0.577) & 0.179 & 1995\\ \hline
Neutral & 0.607 (0.267, 0.947) & 0.000 & 1040\\ \hline
Negative & -0.099 (-0.485, 0.288) & 0.616 & 703\\ \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\end{table}
```

But the result looks like this, with two lines on the top left of the table jutting out beyond its borders. How do I get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: not sure why my commands are all on one line, by the way. that is not how i entered them in the compiler.

Comment: delete the `\\ ` after `\begin{tabular}`

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, when adding code sections highlight them and use the `{}` button in the editor which formats them in a text block (see my edit).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle an answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `\\` after `\begin{tabular}`  It is causing an empty row ended after the first cell, which explains the vertical lines.

You should also delete the `\\`  after the `\end{tabular}` (`\\` outside alignments are almost always wrong)